# Dynamically change circle size openlayers

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers-3, geofencing

I am trying to dynamically increase the circle fence size using :

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#radius", function () {
    circleFeature.set("radius",parseInt($("#radius").val()));
});
```

I initially created the circle using this code:

```
 var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
    circleFeature.set('fenceId', fenceId);
    circleFeature.set('latitude', latitude);
    circleFeature.set('longitude', longitude);
    circleFeature.set('radius', givenRadius);
    circleFeature.set('circleRadius', radius);
    circleFeature.set('desc', desc);
    circleFeature.set('isActive', isActive);
```

When I press type the radius, the keypress event is triggered but the circle shape does not change in size.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing your feature properties but not the properties of your `ol.geom.geometry` or `ol.style.Style`. I suppose your geometry is `ol.geom.Circle`.

Then you can use this instead:

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#radius", function () {
    circleFeature.getGeometry().setRadius(parseInt($("#radius").val()));
});
```

Comment: It says setRadius is not a function.

Comment: Your geometry is `ol.geom.Circle`? Could you provide a JSFiddle with your relevant code?

Comment: You don't setRadius on the geometry but on the style but I think you really need a style function on the vector layer.  See http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html#setStyle and http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter04_06_text_style.html.

Comment: Since the circle is used for geofencing in my opinion the geometry matters here and not just the style. Either way (also for the style) it should be a ol.geom.Circle geometry (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html) and you can set the radius for that circle.

Comment: I solved it by setting the style property and using the radius value inside style constructor.

Answer (score 0):

While [this PR](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5776) is not merged use a style function like:

```
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: feature.get('radius'),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'green'
        })
      })
    })
  ];
};
```

Then:

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#radius", function () {
  circleFeature.set("radius",parseInt($("#radius").val()));
  circleFeature.setStyle(styleFunction);
  circleFeature.changed();
});
```